# CakePHP, NearlyFreeSpeech.net, and MySQL

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pdo, nearlyfreespeech

In the last ~week, my CakePHP site has been unable to connect to a MySQL database. Everything is hosted by NearlyFreeSpeech.net and I don't see any problems with the financial aspects of my account.

Does anyone know what's going on?

I'm able to connect to the database with phpMyAdmin and my automated mysqldump calls have worked fine, so I didn't find out right away.

I tried putting up a new CakePHP site using a fresh download from CakePHP but I get the same error message:

Warning (2): PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Operation timed out (trying to connect via tcp://cakeht.db:3306) [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 177]

Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you called your hosting provider to see if they've made any changes to your account and/or server(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was magically fixed with the passage of time.

The solution then, is to simply wait an unknown number of days.